# Fractional Sobolev norm inverse inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I have

$$\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \leq \|\Delta u\|_{L_2(\Omega)} + \|u\|_{L_2(\Omega)} + \|u\|_{W^{3/2}_2(\partial\Omega_1)} + \|\nabla u \cdot n\|_{W^{1/2}_2(\partial\Omega_2)}$$

I somehow need to bound $\|u\|_{W^{3/2}_2(\partial\Omega_1)}$ and $\|\nabla u \cdot n\|_{W^{1/2}_2(\partial\Omega_2)}$ with the $L_2(\partial\Omega_1)$ and $L_2(\partial\Omega_2)$ norms.

As far as I understand this can not be done in an infinite dimensional sense.

Does there exists an inverse inequality that I can use to do that when $u$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: Which trace theorems do you have in mind? The only trace theorems that I could find are:
$||u||_{H^{3/2} (\partial\Omega)} \leq C ||u||_{H^2(\Omega)}$ 
and $||\nabla_n u||_{H^{1/2} (\partial\Omega)} \leq C ||u||_{H^1(\Omega)}$. But this does not work in my case since the first bound is made in terms of the norm $H^2$, which I want to bound in the first place.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. I think these inequalities are optimal even in finite dimension setting.

Comment: @S. Maths: I see, but if I use them I get:
$$(C_1-1) ||u||_{H_2} \leq C_2||u||_{H_1} + ||\Delta u||_{L_2} + ||u||_{L_2},$$
and the norm positivity can be lost since there is no guarantee that $C_1<1$.

Comment: Yes, in fact I don't see the usefulness of this estimate, because the norm $H^1$ and $L^2$ of Laplacian is almost the $H^2$ norm (just you avoid the mixed derivative). Where you really need this?

Comment: I need this in showing coercivity of a bilinear form on $H^2$ (with nonzero BCs). The bilinear form contains all $L_2$ parts (Laplacian, gradient, undifferentiated) except the mixed derivative.